# Ruby on Rails 2.3.8: Factory_girl: Global Variable doesn't maintain value throughout factory builds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, factory-bot

```
  setup do
     @user = Factory.build(:user)
  end
```

so, at the top of my unit test, I have the above.

And in my unit tests, I do `Factory.build(:object)`

but in the factory itsself, it is saying `NoMethodError: undefined method my_attribute for nil:NilClass`

my factory:

```
Factory.define :object |o| do
   o.my_attribute @user.my_attribute
end
```

but @user is nil =\

Comment: I can't understand why you need a factory there.

Comment: it's an example, I don't use any objects called object, and all my factories are at least 6 lines long. =p

Answer (score 1):

`@user` is not a global variable.  It is an *instance* variable.  In this case, `@user` is an instance variable of the test suite.  The `do...end` block passed to `Factory.define` is not run within the context of the test suite, therefor it will have a different `self` and different instance variables.  Instead, you need to pass the attribute value to the factory:

```
setup do
  @user = Factory.build(:user)
  Factory.build(:object, :my_attribute => @user.my_attribute)
end
```

Comment: i get the same problem with @@user as well